# How to loop through a string in crystal

Tags: loops, input, crystal-reports

I am fairly new too crystal, so sorry if I am being a bit stupid. I have a string:

```
src = gets "> "
```

I am trying to loop through that string but I don't know how... What I have tried:
In cpp, I use `:` to loop through strings(or anything), I tried this, like so:

```
for i : src
  # ...
```

and this:

```
for i: src

  #...
```

And I also tried this:

```
for i >> src
  #...
```

None of those work... I also tried this:

```
for i in src
  # ...
```

Yet again, none of those work... why, and how can I fix this?

My full code:

```
src = gets "> "
for i : src
  if i == '1'
    puts "You entered one."
  end
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with that loop. This doesn't look like crystal reports code. Whats does `cpp` mean? C++?

Comment: @MatSnow I didn't know what tag to put it in.... sorry...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Crystal docs](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.1.1/String.html#each_char(&):Nil-instance-method) using the `each_char` method of String you can iterate over each character in the string.

e.g.

```
array = [] of Char
"ab☃".each_char do |char|
  array << char
end
array # => ['a', 'b', '☃']
```